# setting background color depending on border-width

Tags: jquery, html, css, json

I have a small application that grabs from a JSON file the unemployment rate from countries in Europe. It is displayed in a map and over each country there is a little ball that when hovered over displays the unemployment rate for that country. The size of the ball depends on the countries Unemployment rate. Now what I also want to do is change the background color for the balls depending on the unemployment rate of the country. Here is a JSFiddle so you guys can understand the application better:

http://jsfiddle.net/RSEyg/9/

jQuery for the background:

```
    $('.dataPt').each(function(){
    var border = $(this).css("border-width");
    border = parseInt(border);
    if(border < 10){
        $(this).css("background","yellow");
    }
    else if(border < 16){
        $(this).css("background","pink");
    }
    else if(border  < 21){
        $(this).css("background","black");
    }
    else if(border  < 30){
        $(this).css("background","blue");
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's the solution.

Note that the inline `background-color` was incorrect as the coloring was defined as `border-color` here. The following solves your logic problem and includes that CSS fix:

```
$('.dataPt').each(function () {
    $(this).hover(function () {
        var border = $(this).css("border-width");
        border = parseInt(border);
        if (border >= 25) {
            $(this).css("border-color", "blue");
        } else if (border >= 15 && border < 25) {
            $(this).css("border-color", "black");
        } else if  (border < 15 && border >= 10) {
            $(this).css("border-color", "pink");
        } else {
            $(this).css('border-color', 'red');
        }
    });
});
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/RSEyg/10/

Comment: I checked your fiddle all of the dots are still blue

Comment: That's bc of an issue not related to your question.

Comment: I think I found the greater solution, one sec.

Comment: Your background color was obstructed from view bc the coloring is on the border, not in the background. I fixed in the answer and updated the fiddle.

Comment: Thank you I just checked your fiddle but they are all blue still

Comment: Did you click the new link? They change for me.

Comment: oo I see you put it to change after the hover thank you very much that wasnt needed but I guess its a plus

Comment: Ah, yeah you can remove the hover easily enough. Thanks for the feedback.

Answer (score 1):

Rearrange your `if` blocks, or use `else if`. (If you re-examine your logic you'll see that each `if` condition will always be true if any of the previous conditions are true.) Also, use `$(this)` inside your `each` function rather than using the selector again. **Also** as a quirk of how you are rendering your circles, you need to set `border-color`, not `background-color`.

E.g.

```
if(border < 10){
    $(this).css("border-color","yellow");
}
else if(border < 15){
    $(this).css("border-color","pink");
}
else if(border < 20){
    $(this).css("border-color","black");
}
else if(border < 30){
    $(this).css("border-color","blue");
}
```

You could also simply arrange the checks from 30 down to 10, but this would have the cost of setting the `css` property four times if `border` was less than 10, for example.

Comment: Thank you;however,that did not change anything the reason they are all blue is because the css default color is blue

Comment: Ah, ok. I see what's wrong. You're using `$('.dataPt')` inside the `each`, when you should just use `$(this)`.

Comment: I had it like that before and ended changing it to .dataPt to see if it would fix the issue

Comment: Ok, you must have another issue too. I'll take a look at the fiddle.

Comment: There you go, looks like you have a solution now.

Comment: I changed the fiddle to that but the dots are still blue

Comment: Looks like you need to set your border-color, not your background-color. http://jsfiddle.net/RSEyg/11/